# Highlight part of div

Tags: angular, typescript, highlight

I would like to higlight part of code block, that is inside section on my website:

```
<section highlight-js-content=".highlight">
  <pre class="source-code-box">
    <code class="source-code java highlight">{{sourceCode}}</code>
  </pre>
</section>
```

I getting output like this (sourceCode):

```
import aaaaa;
import aaaab;
import aaaac;

    public class TestA {
   private final Integer a;

   TestA(final Integer a){
     this.a = a;
   }

   getA(){
     return this.a;
   }

   getTwoA(){
     return 2 * this.a;
   }
}
```

let's that I want to entire `getA()` method highlighted in output section.

How can I do that?

PS. I would like to do this without `jQuery`.

**EDIT:**
**SOLVED**:

I found solution in following topic:
[Inject <input> in innerHTML angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303065/inject-input-in-innerhtml-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

as i can see, there is only one way to achieve this is by manually adding a span around the portion of code in your database you want to highlight and then use `[innerHTML]="sourceCode"` to bind your code

```
<span class='higlightCode'>
 getTwoA(){
     return 2 * this.a;
   }
</span>
```

**Bind the html as**

```
<section highlight-js-content=".highlight">
  <pre class="source-code-box">
    <code class="source-code java highlight" [innerHTML]="sourceCode"></code>
  </pre>
</section>
```

**Output will be something like this**

```css
.highlightCode
{
  background-color:#ffeb00
}
```

```html
<section highlight-js-content=".highlight">
  <pre class="source-code-box">
    <code class="source-code java highlight">
import aaaaa;
import aaaab;
import aaaac;

    public class TestA {
   private final Integer a;

   TestA(final Integer a){
     this.a = a;
   }
<span class='highlightCode'>
   getA(){
     return this.a;
   }
</span>
   getTwoA(){
     return 2 * this.a;
   }
}
    </code>
  </pre>
</section>
```

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand you, but I scarping source code from raw file like: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links/master/helloworlds/3.8-json/pom.xml. I dont have code in database.

Comment: if you are getting data from raw file the how do know which portion of code you want to highlight is their any perticular function which you want to highlight in that case you have to search for that function in `sourceCode` and you have to append this span around it

Comment: As I know you cant inject HTML directive in typescript/javascript variable, but I will check it.

Comment: As I though. You cant inject html, style, url, resource url into variable because of security contexts.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#xss