# Not able to replace string by text box in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to replace __ by text box in Angular 2/4. Here at below link I have example.

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajkvyq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
```

Comment: Please, remove `angularjs` tag. This tag is reserved to `angular 1.x` questions

Comment: By the way, I didn't understand your question. That's not even a textbox!

Comment: @Cristian Traìna  There is not any text box. I have a String and which contains __. I wanted to replace every __ by a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsanitized HTML cannot be bound in component template, it should be [marked as sanitized first](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwsp7i?file=app/app.component.ts):

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

replaceFillBlanks(question): SafeHtml {
  var $inputBox = '<input type="text" name="fillBox"/>';

  let q = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(question.replace(/__/g,$inputBox));
  return q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular sanitizes your HTML in order to prevent XSS attacks. You can't inject html so easily! You need to sanitize it.

You can use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value: string)` and read more about this [over here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

Pay attention, it's supposed that you know what you are doing:

> These situations should be very rare, and extraordinary care must be taken to avoid creating a Cross Site Scripting (XSS) security bug!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  question = "How are __ doing today ?. I'm doing __.";

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

  replaceFillBlanks(question){
      var $inputBox = '<input type="text" name="fillBox"/>';

      // if you'll replace any other string except text box this will work fine. 
      //var $inputBox = 'hi';

      let q = question.replace(/__/g,$inputBox);
      console.log(q);
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(q);
    }
}
```

Ref: [Inject <input> in innerHTML angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303065/inject-input-in-innerhtml-angular-2)